# How to see/write persian letters in mysql 8 commad line client

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, farsi, mysql-command-line-client

I have created database with Persian words in MySQL workbench, and it creates/shows them perfectly:

```
create database تست;
show databases;
```

[image]

but when I try to view them in MySQL command line client, it shows ‘???’:

[image]

and when I try `set names utf8mb4;`:

[image]

And trying to execute these in command line client:

```
create database `تست`;
show databases;
```

[image]

Then I've changed font to "Courier new":

[image]

Still ?????

Comment: Please run this query: `SELECT VERSION();` and let us know what it returns.

Comment: It says `8.0.35`

Comment: The default character set should be utf8mb4 already. You must have configured it differently. Check your `my.cnf` file.

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried testing this: `CREATE SCHEMA \`متن فارسی\`;` and then `SHOW SCHEMAS;` and both worked fine. I am testing on MySQL 8.2.0. If I `SET NAMES latin1;` then it fails, and shows only ??? ?????.

Comment: At first place it shows `CREATE SCHEMA `?????`;`. I changed font to Courier new, and it shows persian characters. But when I `SHOW SCHEMAS;` again shows these ?????.

Comment: The fact that it works in MySQL Workbench suggests that MySQL Server is configured correctly. Perhaps the terminal window app is interfering with correct character encoding, both input and output? Anyway, this question doesn't seem like it's related to a code problem.

Comment: How can I do the input and output correct character encoding?